# Output the result of an input generator and then the result of a translation of the result of the generator

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

The following code:

```
def test(x):
    for i in x:
        yield i
        i = list(i)
        i[1] = "X"
        yield tuple(i)

list(test(it.product(["A", "B"], ["C"])))
```

Outputs the following list:

```
[('A', 'C'), ('A', 'X'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'X')]
```

How would I adapt the function such that the input generator results are listed first and then the results of the translation?

So:

```
[('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'X'), ('B', 'X')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def test(x):
    x = list(x)
    yield from x
    for i in x:
        i = list(i)
        i[1] = "X"
        yield tuple(i)
```

or

```
def test(x):
    x1, x2 = it.tee(x)
    yield from x1
    for i in x2:
        i = list(i)
        i[1] = "X"
        yield tuple(i)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=vZFBCsIwEEVxm1MMWbVQhXYlggv1EkLpQmyCA2kT0imkC0_iphs9lKcxTa2CdO3fzWf-zIN_e5iOLrru-3tLcrl-Lq5YGW0JkIQlrVUDp8YPjJVCAomGIhdvGHg52ILCYIS5Q6FKkFZX4IIhtQUErMGNgUE4hTD-enlaeJsf-ccab1FrlBg2mbFYUxSCgQFpZawu2zNFOd_xBPieFwnk_MCL2GsON03AZf6Pz5IQc9TpD3b2d-6xhXcZUykv)

Comment: @LaurentB. What trick?

Comment: the use of ` yield from` and ` it.tee`, well thought

Comment: @LaurentB. Meh, I agree with ["you come to regard these techniques for what they are: language features rather than tricks"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html).

Answer (score -1):

## Solution 1:

Inside of `test` function first, we are converting `x` to `list` so we can iterate through `x` multiple times. In the first loop we are yielding the values in `x` and in second loop we are inserting the value `'X'`.

```
import itertools as it

def test(x):
    l = list(x)
    for i in l:
        yield i
    for i in l:
        i = list(i)
        i[1] = "X"
        yield tuple(i)

print(list(test(it.product(["A", "B"], ["C"]))))
```

Output:

```
[('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'X'), ('B', 'X')]
```

## Solution 2:

Here we have used `yield from` to yield multiple values.

```
import itertools as it

def test(x):
    vals = list(x)
    yield from vals
    yield from ((v1, "X") for v1, v2 in vals)


print(list(test(it.product(["A", "B"], ["C"]))))
```

Comment: I don't think it's useful to post a worse version of an already posted solution.

Comment: @KellyBundy when I started answering the question there was no solution posted only after posting  I realized that someone else has already posted. However I realized both of our approaches were different.

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't call it a different approach. Do you see advantages in yours? I only see disadvantages.